# CorrelationId is Null when using serilog enricher nuget package

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights, serilog

[image]

I wanted to populate a value for correlationId to my applicationInsights . Right now the value is null. I have installed the serilog.enrichers.correlationId nuget package and have services.AddHTTPContextAccessor in my startup.cs file, but still the value of correlationId is null. Am i Missing something?Any suggestions?
I got the source from :- https://github.com/ekmsystems/serilog-enrichers-correlation-id

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
```

the above is my logger configuration in startup.cs. all the other enrichers that i defined in Enrich tag in appsettings.json are being populated but the correlation id is null.

Comment: Is there any progress? Could you pls accept my post as the answer if it's helpful to you? Any further questions can freely added here. Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 1):

Did you respect this? You need to call `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`
[https://github.com/ekmsystems/serilog-enrichers-correlation-id#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20register%20the%20IHttpContextAccessor%20singleton%20so%20that%20the%20enricher%20has%20access%20to%20the%20requests%20HttpContext%20so%20that%20it%20can%20attach%20the%20correlation%20ID%20to%20the%20request/response](https://github.com/ekmsystems/serilog-enrichers-correlation-id#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20register%20the%20IHttpContextAccessor%20singleton%20so%20that%20the%20enricher%20has%20access%20to%20the%20requests%20HttpContext%20so%20that%20it%20can%20attach%20the%20correlation%20ID%20to%20the%20request/response)

Answer (score 1):

In Net 6 I configured logging of CorrelationId this way:

1. Installed the packages Serilog.AspNetCore and Serilog.Enrichers.CorrelationId.
2. In `Program.cs` file I added:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .CreateLogger();
   
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctxt, cfg) => cfg
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctxt.Configuration));
```

3. And in `appsettings.json` file:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithCorrelationId" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | {CorrelationId} | {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Example of using:

```
Log.Information("Starting of method GetPayments");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my test result:

[image]

And what I did like below:

In my asp.net core application, install related packages first, then edit the `Program.cs` -> `CreateHostBuilder` ：

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                }).UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration).Enrich.WithCorrelationId()
                    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {CorrelationId} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration { InstrumentationKey = "your_instrumentation_key" }, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
             );
```

My packages:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.CorrelationId" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```